# Oracle NLS_UPPER Index Columns

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table and it has an index with 3 columns. One of these column is NSL_UPPER("CODE"). When I select the columns of index from  ALL_IND_COLUMNS or from  DBA_IND_COLUMNS, it returns "SYS_NC00101$" for the NSL_UPPER("CODE"). How can I reach the index column with name NSL_UPPER("CODE") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS instead of ALL_IND_COLUMNS
function based indexes are based on expressions instead of columns

Comment: Thank you so much. I analyzed and there are many function based indexes. But just one of them has a trouble. Why just one of them? Do you have an idea?